# Upload image to canvas and show in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Currently, we have HTML page to upload image and load on canvas.

```
function handleImage2(e) {
  var ctx = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.font = "50px Arial";
  ctx.fillText('Loading...', 100, 100);

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

For further development, we want to display the same image on different page and on new tab. The process flow is when user click the button `more detail`, a new tab opened with same image and some information followed.

I have try to simulate submit process to another page and get POST data from the previous page. But this method doesn't works and make browser so laggy and at the end nothing show up.

```
var apiForm = document.createElement("form");
apiForm.target = "_blank";    
apiForm.method = "POST";
apiForm.action = "printout.php";

var urlData = document.createElement("input");
urlData.type = "text";
urlData.name = "urlData";
urlData.value = canvasObject.toDataURL("image/png");

apiForm.appendChild(urlData);

document.body.appendChild(apiForm);

apiForm.submit();
```

Following @PHPGLue guy on this comment bellow, I've following his idea and still doesn't work

```
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var dataUrl = canvasObject.toDataURL("image/png");

var newWindow = window.open("printout.php", "print preview", "_blank");
newWindow.document.getElementById('canvas2').src = dataUrl;
```

Is there any idea to show image from canvas and then show the same image on another canvas in different new tab page?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just pass the link of the image?

Comment: Why are you drawing on the canvas? Do you just want an image that is uploaded to appear on the page?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I don't uploaded that image to server, just for preview.

Comment: I think that this logic is wrong anyway ...

Comment: No need to put it on canvas. If you just assign `event.target.result` (or `this.result`) in `reader.onload`  to `img.src` you're done. `img.src = this.result;`

Comment: @MarcoSalerno The idea is image processing on client side. We do computer vision using deep learning algorithm on Server Side, then in client side, using javascript marking image on canvas and user can preview with some information on the left side with click button `preview`. Preview button meaning more larger display image with some detail information

Comment: @PHPglue is it can be done on another page? I mean on new tab?

Comment: `var newWindow = open();` `newWindow` is now a total different window that you can createElement on or whatever. Of course you may want to create the page to begin with then open it, so you don't have to create Elements. Once you've got an Element on that page with an id, let's say `newWindow.document.getElementById('new_image_id_here').src = this.result;`. See [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for documentation. Note that you can always leave off the `window` as it is implicit when referring to the `window` you already have open.

Comment: @PHPglue Have try your idea and doesn't work at all. Please review my code, I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to PHPglue for his Idea.

This problem can be done using this method

```
var canvasObject = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var dataUrl = canvasObject.toDataURL("image/png");

var newWindow = open("printout.php", "print preview", "_blank");

newWindow.onload = function(){
  var canvasObj = newWindow.document.getElementById('canvas2');
  var ctx = canvasObj.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image;

  img.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }

  img.src = dataUrl;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Example:

**upload.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Upload Window</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='upload.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='main'>
      <form id='frm' name='frm'>
        <input id='up' name='up' type='file' />
        <input id='pv' name='pv' type='button' value='preview' />
      </form>
      <div id='output'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**otherwindow.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Other Window</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='main'>
      <img id='output' />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**upload.js**

```
$(function(){
var w, r;
$('#frm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
$('#up').change(function(){
  var t = $(this), fl = t.prop('files')[0];
  if(fl.type.match(/^image\//i)){
    var f = new FileReader;
    f.onload = function(){
      var img = document.createElement('image');
      r = img.src = this.result; $('#output').html(img);
    }
    f.readAsDataURL(fl);
  }
});
$('#pv').click(function(){
  if(r){
    if(!w){
      w = open('otherwindow.php', 'Other Window');
    }
    w.$('#output').attr('src', r);
  }
});
});
```